# Execute Bulk Insert Task where SQL Server user has Bulk Insert permission but no permissions over file

Tags: sql-server, ssis, bulkinsert

I have the following problem. I have a database server with a user, let's call it `sql_admin` (a SQL Server user). This user can do `BULK INSERT` over tables.

I also have another user in a filesystem server, called `sql_usr` (a domain user). This user has permissions over files I have to load through the `BULK INSERT`.

However, due to security concerns, the `sql_admin` user cannot have permissions over those files, and the `sql_usr` cannot have permissions to do `BULK INSERT` operations.

Is there any way to set the Bulk Insert Task so that it accesses the file using the `sql_usr` credentials and do the `BULK INSERT` with the `sql_admin` credentials?

Thanks

Comment: So if the file is on a network share, sql_usr would then move/copy the file to a local folder (using a task, sql job, package, etc.) on the same server in which your SQL server is being hosted like D:/ImportFiles.  Then sql_admin should have access to the file as it is in a local folder and it should be able to bulk insert.

Comment: @ArleighReyna: thanks, but that's not an option neither.

Comment: what about giving the sql_user permission to bulk insert to a temporary database/location and then use your sql_admin to do the load from the temporary location?  If you let us know why the constraints are there such as our DBA doesn't allow us to give bulk insert or domain admins don't let us modify permissions then we will have a better understanding of how to guide you.  Also does it have to be bulkinsert what about openrowset? Could sql-user have access to openrowset to file share and load to the table and or temporary?

Comment: The only two other options I can think of is 1) Create an SSIS package that will run under user sql_usr and use SQL Authentication with the sql_admin account to actually do the upload into SQL. Option 2, which is a little more complicated and may be slow is to run.  Create a PowerShell script to be run under sql_usr to read the file into memory so that way it does not matter where the file is actually stored then do a for each loop in the PowerShell script for each row to insert the data from memory into SQL again using SQL authentication under the sql_admin account.